# Stripe Subscription Period

Tags: stripe-payments

I got charge.php making my subscription. The issue I noticed is the period is from today -> the following date the next year.

What happens at the end of the period:

screenshot: http://d.pr/i/6MEn

Does stripe make another invoice from feb 2017 - feb 2018? Or do I need to do some coding to make sure a users subscription never stops until they cancel it?

Thanks! Sorry if its been asked, but I searched.

Here is my code for a new user, to make the user - make the plan - add the user to the custom plan (since it's a donation form, user picks the amount and the term to run (every month, 3 months, 6 months, etc)

```
    $stripe_new_customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
        "source" => $token,
        "description" => $name,
        "email" => $email,
        "metadata" => array("order_id" => $order_id, "source" => "Website Online Donation")
    ));

    $customer_id = $stripe_new_customer->id;

    $stripe_plan = \Stripe\Plan::create(array(
        "amount" => $amount,
        "interval" => "month",
        "interval_count" => $term,
        "name" => "Recurring Donation",
        "currency" => "usd",
        "id" => $plan_name
        )
    );

    $customer_made = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($customer_id);
    $customer_made->subscriptions->create(array("plan" => $plan_name));

    $plan_remove = \Stripe\Plan::retrieve($plan_name);
    $plan_remove->delete();
```

Comment: subscriptions automatically renew

Comment: thanks, I guess I can't mark it as answered if its a comment. or can i?

Answer (score 0):

Stripe's subscriptions renew indefinitely until they are canceled, either manually (by sending a [cancel subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#cancel_subscription) API request), or automatically after too many failed payments if that's how you set it in your [subscriptions settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/recurring).